Keyboard mapping partially wrong with Remmina RDP from Fedora 40 to Windows 11
I am using "Remmina 1.4.35 (git n/a)" to connect from my Fedora 40 laptop into a Windows 11 desktop machine. All seems to work fine except for the keyboard mapping. Letters, numbers, and keys like -, =, [, etc., work fine. However, all keys like left shift, tab, space bar, enter, ←, →, backspace, etc. are mapped to wrong things like some letters, volume up, mute, etc. In both computers the keyboard layout is the same (US). I also tried things I found around for the settings (see screenshots below) but this is not fixed. The local keyboard in each machine works fine.




Is it possible Remmina captures those key presses for its shortcuts? My first thought was maybe the remote computer was set to Dvorak, but that wouldn't affect the various function keys giving you trouble. Just let us know about anything more you find. I hope we can help.

Confirm on fedora silverblue and remmina from flatpak. RPM version couldn't check, didn't work because of Failed to create OpenH264 decoder
But I reinstalled remmina from flatpak but from flathub (and not from default fedora repo) And it works now as expected.
